# Enemies wont rotate on collision with spinning wheel

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]In my game enemies are shot out from a cannon onto a spinning wheel. I want them to stick onto the spinning object on collision and spin in the direction of the spinning wheel.

Here's the code I have for when the enemy collides with the spinning circle.

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Spinner")
    {

        joint = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint2D>();

        joint.connectedBody = collision.rigidbody;

    }

}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Would making the enemies a child gameObject of the spinning wheel on collision and then use code to manually spin the enemies on the spinning wheel suit your needs? Or do you need a more physics based approach?

Comment: Hey @MSvenTorjusC1999 I think a physics-based approach would be better.. I've attached a gif to give more context. The triangles are the enemies which I would like to stick and rotate around the wheel.

Comment: What exactly happens when you attach them using the FixedJoint2D? And what is supposed to happen once they are attached to the spinning wheel? Do they get flung off at a certain point and need to maintain their momentum? Or do they literally just need to go around in a circle? I just need more context to figure out what the best approach is.